# Test some conditions using XSL 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

1) How to check if the number variable has only 4 digits using XSL1.0.

```
<xsl:variable name="number" select="0715" />
```

2) How to check if the version variable has a numeric digit followed by an upper case using XSL1.0

```
<xsl:variable name="version" select="V1" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) How to check if the number variable has only 4 digits using XSL1.0.

```
<xsl:variable name="number" select="0715" />
```

This is impossible, because the value of $number is exactly the same as if you wrote

```
<xsl:variable name="number" select="715" />
```

The insignificant zero disappears long before you can test for its presence. So perhaps you just want `($number &lt; 10000)`?

On the other hand, if you're testing that a string comprises exactly four digits, use `translate($x, '0123456789', '9999999999') = '9999'`.

> 2) How to check if the version variable has a numeric digit followed by an upper case using XSL1.0

Depends a little what you mean by "followed" - can there be anything in between? If you mean 'immediately followed', then you can use the same trick:

```
translate(substring($x, 1, 1), '0123456789', '9999999999') = '9' 
 and 
translate(substring($x, 2, 1), 'ABCD...XYZ', 'Z') = 'Z'
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the `string-length()` function to determine the ... well, the length of a string.
2. You could test for:

   `translate($version, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA0000000000') = 'A0'`

**Note**: This tests for a single upper case character followed by a single digit - IOW, the string "V1" *passes* this test.

Note also that your variable points to an *element* named `V1`, not to a string containing "V1".

Comment: What is the meaning of this? @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@##########

Comment: @Joe It has no meaning - it's a string of 26 "@" characters (one for each letter of the alphabet) and 10 "#" characters (one for each digit). This way all alpha characters are translated to "@" and all digits become "#". Actually, I have a better idea - see my edit.